# Zenity - How to connect zenity with Database?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, zenity

guys.

I want to connect my zenity script, which is for an airline reservation system to my sqlite database or phpmyadmin.

Help will be appreciated!

Comment: It is impossible to help you without you providing the code.

Comment: actually  i have a project of OS in my 3rd year,

Comment: where i need to make Airline reservation system  using zenity language,  but i dont find any tutorial  which helps me out in working the zenity with Database